# How to automatically open the debugger whenever `kill-buffer` is invoked?

Tags: debugging, kill-buffer, debug

I'm using Elpy for Python development, and when I run code with `C-c C-c` the source buffer closes -- which I don't want.  Have to constantly reopen.

One idea is to set a breakpoint in `kill-buffer` - except upon doing `C-h f on kill-buffer` I find that it's written in C source code.  How then would I debug invocations of `kill-buffer`?

Answer (score 3):

`M-x debug-on-entry kill-buffer`

That opens the standard Emacs debugger whenever `kill-buffer` is invoked. It doesn't matter that it's a built-in (primitive, not coded in Lisp).

See the Elisp manual, nodes [Function Debugging](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Debugging.html) and [Using Debugger](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Debugger.html).

Comment: Thanks - that's useful - although it's already raising new questions.

It opens a *Backtrace* buffer with the call stack.  It seems that elpy is very sensitive to this - just scrolling through my source file provokes breaks into *Backtrace*.  Then if I attempt to move the mouse from the source buffer to *Backtrace*, *Backtrace* disappears.
 
... I wrote more .. but stackex tells me "too long by 400 chars."  Ah - https://pastebin.com/YjP0FNcw

Comment: Buffers are a data type in Emacs -- they are created and killed behind the scenes all the time.  Consider the `with-temp-buffer` macro, for instance.  You can expect `kill-buffer` to be called frequently.

Comment: What @phils said. The answer tells you how to do it, but it's better to tell you that you probably don't want to do it, except maybe briefly, just to see which function initially invoked `kill-buffer`.